# MediaPlayer unable to create

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Can anyone explain why I get these errors.

```
07-26 13:53:20.169: E/MediaPlayer(10391): Unable to to create media player
07-26 13:53:20.179: E/SurfaceViewVideoActivity(10391): IOException
07-26 13:53:20.179: E/SurfaceViewVideoActivity(10391): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
```

I am trying to play an audio file in my assets folder named 'Tiger.mp3'. Here is my code:

```
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        try
        {
            mediaplayer.setDisplay(holder);
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("Tiger.mp3");
            mediaplayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
            mediaplayer.prepare();
        }
catch//
    }
```

Similar issues were resolved by changing to format of the audio file from .wav to .mp3, but seeing as the file I'm trying to play is already .mp3 I'm a bit confused.
Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

This is how you play media

```
private void play(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
           myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
           myPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
           myPlayer.prepare();
           myPlayer.start();


           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Start play the recording...", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```